# facebook php sdk getuser() returns 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

seems as of late facebook app registration/login is starting to hang a bit and then return 0.

building my login url using the following method

```
$data['loginUrl']   =   $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,status_update',
                                                                       'redirect_uri'=>base_url()."social/walkup/facebook_save/")
                                                                );
```

and when i direct the user through this link i and they bounce to my facebook_save method- getUser() is returning 0 - the url parameter contains the state and code method- but it seems getUser() js hanging- takes a few seconds for the page to render and then it returns 0-

the first line in the new page is

```
$user_details = $this->facebook->getUser();

if($user_details){  //user is logged in
```

the if statement returns false even though the user has accepted the application? is this a facebook bug or any tips?

it some times works fine and some times doesnt

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.4, you must edit your base_facebook.php

https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/

Answer (score 0):

Have found out, that if You configure Facebook Application with "App on Facebook" data, and then visit Canvas Page url, suddenly everything start to work ok. The, even if You visit Your site via direct url, getUser() returns what it should.